# Hide Bing maps coordinates for the user

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, bing-maps

Is it possible to hide the Bing maps coordinates for the user ?

This is my javascript code:

`var mapOptions = {
                credentials : "My app code here",
                zoom:@(Model.Sprint.ZoomFactor),
                center:new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude),
                showDashboard: false,
                disableUserInput: true,
                enableSearchLogo: false,
                enableClickableLogo: false
            };`

In my html source, the coordinates become visible to the user but the user is not allowed to see where the exact location is.

Does anyone know how to hide them?

Im using ASP.net MVC 3 so the coordinates come from a viewmodel.

thanks.

Comment: Are you implying you're concerned about them "viewing source" and seeing the coordinates?

Comment: That is correct. Im gonna have to look at the design so that it will be impossible to show the coordinates. The user cannot may not see the exact location since it is a contest.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using the Bing maps javascript control, you cannot really hide this information from the user.  The code is running on the user's machine, so how can you hide your source code and data from them?  If your requirement is that the coordinates should not be visible in the downloaded source code, you can try something similar to the Bing interactive SDK, where they use an ajax call issued by the client to obtain the map license key at run time. But this is easily defeated by stepping through the code using the javascript debugging feature on your browser.